# how to delete/destroy the store when window is closed extjs 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

forum member i am having one problem described below.

**How can I destroy or delete the store when the popup window is close**, I want to do that because the window loaded doesn't contain the updated data. **So as soon as the window is closed the store will be deleted .**

Again when the window popup it is created completely **new, load all the Stores, Models and View associated with it.**

I tried it but haven't yet successful any one having any idea, how can I solve it may suggest me.

I am using extjs 4.0.2a and Java

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the code of where the store is associated to its view/controller?

A wild guess will be that if you move the config into initComponent, the store will be deleted as soon as the view/controller is destroyed.

Comment: thanks.. have a look to the added link I had my detailed question with code there **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156816/window-not-showing-the-updated-data-based-on-grid-row-double-clicked**